# How do I can tranform a cataegorical variable to continuos variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, categorical-data, continuous

I have a DataFrame with many variables such as percentage, year, hectares and others, but I have one that is the distance, I am evaluating the direct impact (area directly impacted) and the extent of this impact by buffers in km around the direct impact and I compare it to the control.
I have:

At this point, my variables are categorical, even though they represent distances.

```
 Distances:"dirImpct",1km","2km","3km","4km","5km","6km","7km","8km","9km","10km","20km","30km","40km","50km","60km","70km", "controle")
```

I want something like this:

```
Distances:  dirImpct < km < control
DirImpact= distance  0
km= distances, (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70)
control= distances > 70
```

Comment: i think you have to remove the letters `km` to make the variable continuous in nature. Take a look at the `str_replace` function from the [stringr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_replace) library.

Answer (score 0):

You may transform to `factor` and rename the `levels`.

```
dat$Distances <- factor(dat$Distances)
lvl <- levels(dat$Distances)
levels(dat$Distances)[c(length(lvl) - 1, length(lvl))] <- 
  c("0", "dist > 70")
dat
#             x Distances
# 1  -0.5448391 dist > 70
# 2  -0.7178019       1km
# 3   0.8157044       2km
# 4   0.2789727       3km
# 5   0.4940412       4km
# 6   0.4096203       5km
# 7  -0.9503315       6km
# 8  -0.3750518       7km
# 9   0.3385260       8km
# 10  0.3666900       9km
# 11  0.9265970      10km
# 12  0.2554600      20km
# 13  1.4776808      30km
# 14 -0.3211048      40km
# 15 -0.9469399      50km
# 16 -0.1853323      60km
# 17 -0.4438878      70km
# 18 -1.0206900         0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(length(Distances)),
           Distances=c("dirImpct","1km","2km","3km","4km","5km","6km","7km",
                      "8km","9km","10km","20km","30km","40km","50km","60km",
                      "70km", "controle")
)
```